# a Very simple example

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

When talking of functions that are Riemann integrable but not Lebesgue integrable  we always give the example of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ on $]0,\infty [$ but my question is : is it the same with $f(x)=x$ on $]-\infty,\infty [$ and if so why never use this as an example??

Comment: $f(x) = x$ is neither Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable on $[-\infty,\infty)$. The associated limits both diverge

Comment: You're confusing an improper integral with its Cauchy principal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=x$ is not Riemann integrable, in improper sense, or Lebesgue integrable.